# Start playing Bioshock

Tags: bioshock-series

I was young when Bioshock 1 came out and did not have a PC strong enough to play it. Over the past years I forgot about it but saw other Bioshock titles coming out but I never had a closer look at it.

Now I'm thinking about playing them but I don't know where to start... Is it necessary to play all the Bioshock games through to understand the story or can I just start with Bioshock Infinite? Is the story even connected in all the games?

Please no spoilers :*

Comment: Its not necessary, but I would recommend purely because they are all fantastic games. And as mentioned below the genre gradually changes as you progress through the series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need to play Bioshock or Bioshock 2 to understand most of Bioshock Infinite's plot. However, for the Burial at Sea expansions, having finished the first Bioshock game is crucial for understanding the story.

Answer (score 2):

Playing in chronological order makes the most sense in this case, as the games make reference to the previous in the series, which might cause a little confusion for someone new to the games. The order to play the games in is up to you, though it is worth noting that the games change genre slightly as they go:

Horror<----------------------->Action

Bioshock|Bioshock 2|Bioshock Infinite

Comment: This is probably the only series I know of where this is not true, at all. The first two games are completely unrelated to the main storyline of the third, and they are only loosely held together in backstory.

Comment: @Timelord64 hence I said make reference, as there is no real connection.

Comment: Infinite might not be dark and dingy, but that doesn't mean it's not a psychological thriller... ;)

Comment: Chronological by story or chronological by release date?

Answer (score 1):

I never played the second Bioshock and I don't even think that would have changed the fact that I enjoyed the third. The stories aren't (entirely) related and that makes it perfect to start with the Bioshock you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

For Bioshock 2, Bioshock 1 is a must. 
I am not sure about Bioshock Infinite, but I hear that they changed a lot in the latest release.

Bioshock 1 is the best, in my opinion.